# get all occurence of a regex in string python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find in the following string `TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/Node[1]` this :

```
TreeModel/Node
TreeModel/Node/Node[1]
TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]
TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/Node[1]
```

**Using regular expression** in python. Here is the code I tried:

```
string = 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/Node[1]'
pattern = r'.+?Node\[[1-9]\]'
print re.findall(pattern=pattern,string=string)
#result : ['TreeModel/Node/Node[1]', '/Node[4]', '/Node[1]']
#expected result : ['TreeModel/Node', 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]', 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]', 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/Node[1]']
```

Comment: Cannot understand what you exactly want to find...

Comment: I want a regular expression that gives me the result I've put at the begining from my path.

Comment: You didn't say what is wrong with the result.

Comment: So you want four lines of output on that one?

Comment: @revo yes correct. I've modified the code and added the expected result.

Comment: `re.findall` specifically returns non-overlapping matches, so that's not the right idea. Does `/` ever appear in the intervening strings, i.e. not as a path separator? If not then using `string.split('/')` and working with the resulting list is probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @AlexHall unfortunately the character `/`can be part of my string... That what makes me wanna use regex.

Comment: I see in your own regex you have `Node\[\d+\]` and your input string is limited to this. Where a slash can appear then? and what should be the output?

Comment: @revo here is an example: `{http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_3}TreeModel/{http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_3}Node` I've removed that for simplification

Comment: So they are within braces always?

Comment: @revo yes they are.

Comment: See here https://ideone.com/qoOfMk

Comment: Thanks @revo that worked like a charme. You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good in Python at all but for regex part with your specific structure of string below regex matches each segment:

```
/?(?:{[^{}]*})?[^/]+
```

Where braces and preceding `/` is optional. It matches a slash mark (if any) then braces with their content (if any) then the rest up to next slash mark.

Python code (see live [demo here](https://ideone.com/qoOfMk)):

```
matches = re.findall(r'/?(?:{[^{}]*})?[^/]+', string)
output = ''
for i in range(len(matches)):
  output += matches[i];
  print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use split here:

```
>>> s = 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/Node[1]'
>>> split_s = s.split('/')
>>> ['/'.join(split_s[:i]) for i in range(2, len(split_s)+1)]
['TreeModel/Node',
 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]',
 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]',
 'TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/Node[1]']
```

You can also use regex:

```
for i in range(2, s.count('/')+2):
    s_ = '[^/]+/*'
    regex = re.search(r'('+s_*i+')', s).group(0)
    print(regex)
TreeModel/Node/
TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/
TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/
TreeModel/Node/Node[1]/Node[4]/Node[1]
```

Comment: as I said in the comment to @AlexHall the character `/`can be part of the string so this might not work.

Comment: there is already `/` in your input string, not sure what you are asking?